load byte and store byte problem when reversing a string in MIPS?
I am trying to reverse a string in assembly. I am new to it so I have no idea how to debug. This is the current code.
## $a0 --> address of string
## $v0 --> string length

reverse_string:
    j string_length # this subroutine works
    la $t3, STR_str # contains the string
    
    div $t9, $v0, 2 # divide string length by 2
    add $t8, $zero, $zero # this is the counter
    sub $v0, $v0, 1 # string length - 1
    add $t7, $t3, $v0 # offset by string length - 1 to find last character
    j reverse_string_loop

reverse_string_loop:
    beq $t8, $t9, end_for_all # check if it has reached the halfway point
    lb $t1, 0($t7)     # load last character into $t1
        lb $t2, 0($t3)     # load current character into $t2
        sb $t1, 0($t3)     # store last character at current location
        sb $t2, 0($t7)     # store current character at last location
    add $t3, $t3, 1 
    sub $t7, $t7, 1
    add $t8, $t8, 1

I have only a limited idea on how storing and loading works in MIPS, so I'm guessing the problem is that.
It is supposed to reverse the string, but as of the moment it is not doing anything to the test string. I didn't write the main, but if it helps, this is how it's structured:
### reverse_string
##

li  $v0, 4
la $a0, STR_reverse_string
syscall

la $a0, STR_str
jal reverse_string

la $a0, STR_str
jal print_test_string


lw  $ra, 0($sp) # POP return address
addi    $sp, $sp, 4


jr  $ra

These errors pop up when I try to run it:
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000004
Bad address in text read: 0x00000005
The console said something about bad instruction address, but I'm not sure where that is occuring.

For starters, verify that string_length does not destory $a0 as that is usually call clobbered.

Thank you @Jester ! I tried loading the address of the first character of the string to another register after calling string_length, but it still gave me the same error saying bad instruction address. I've edited the post to show the changes!

You're not calling string length properly.  Function calling is sadly complicated in assembly.
First, you must pass string length a return address.  The return address is a mechanism that allows the same function to be called from different callers, at different levels of the call chain, even from different call sites in the same caller, and still be able to return to the proper caller.  One thing to appreciate is that code/instructions live in memory — and this means that each instruction in the code has its own unique address!  The return address mechanism uses this fact to capture the unique address of the instruction to execute next after a function that has been call completes and needs to return to its caller.
The return address is typically passed by using jal instruction, which captures a return address into $ra for later use by that function to return to the exactly right caller.  We don't see return addresses materialized in C or other languages beyond assembly, however, virtually all assembly languages make you deal with the concept of return address in some way or another.
We can see in the code that you're using j instead of jal.  That the PC=0004 in the exception is another indication that no good return address was passed into string length.
Functions must end by an explicit return to their caller.  On MIPS, this is typically done using jr $ra as the last instruction.
Second, when crossing call boundaries, register usages should be observed.  A called function is allowed to use some registers without concern (call-clobbered) and others can be used by their original values must be returned to the caller (call-preserved).  Conversely, callers must not rely on call-clobbered registers surviving a function call, yet they can rely on call-preserved registers to survive.  In order for such system to work (sharing fixed, limited set of CPU registers amount potentially thousands of function in a large program), all functions must play by the rules (to any other observing functions).
These rules can be omitted/optimized for custom scenarios, though typically that is done for performance, not necessarily for coursework while learning the standard calling convention.

Because main calls your reverse_string, and that in turn calls string_length, you will have to learn about creating a stack frame and save/restore prologue/epilogue, and follow the standard calling convention.
The fundamental concept of register preservation applies to many registers, but let's look at the $ra register usage in (an abstraction of) the dynamic instruction stream.
Fundamentally, this sequence won't work because
    jal reverse_string    # main calls reverse string
                          # sets return address to next instr in main
    jal string_length     # reverse_string calls string_length
                          # sets return address to next instr in reverse_string
    jr $ra                # string_length returns to reverse_string
    ...
    jr $ra                # reverse_string returns to main***

***In order to make this work we have to save and restore the original incoming $ra value for reverse_string — this because the jal to call string_length repurposes $ra and if we don't save that original incoming value somewhere else, then that repurposing means loosing the prior value.

The code you're showing does not engage in a loop.  Perhaps you left off the last instruction, and, we don't see the label end_for_all, so obviously some code is missing.

The way we debug assembly language is pretty much the same as any other language — run one line at a time and verify that each line does what it should (and nothing it shouldn't).
Try using the debugger to single step and observe what happens where.  Each instruction should further the program by advancing the state (of registers + memory).  Observe the program state and control flow between instructions.  When something diverges from your expectations, then fix issues there.  Sometime the problem is earlier in the code yet went unobserved in debugging until later — that happens so we have to be wary.
